# PHP Undefined index in image upload

Tags: php, mysql, html, file-upload

I am trying to upload an image to be stored in a database on mysql however I keep receiving an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: profilepic in >[php-path]/tuto>rsignupsubmit.php on line 17

There is a simple button upload of type file on a form:

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Profile Picture</label>
    <input class="button" type="file" name="profilepic">
</div>
```

I then have this code on another submit page, I am quite new to PHP however I have searched and searched and cannot find a solution anywhere.

```
//File upload
$target_dir = "../img/";
$newprofilepic = $target_dir . basename($_FILES ["profilepic"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($newprofilepic,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

$newlocation = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['location']);
$insertquery = "INSERT INTO tutors(name, username, password, email, mobile, 
profilepic, location, 
message)"."VALUES('$newname','$newusername','$newpassword','$newemail', 
'$newmobile', '$newprofilepic', '$newlocation', '$newmessage')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $insertquery) or die(mysqli_error($conn));


mysqli_close($conn);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to do var_dump($_FILES); in order to see what exactly your server is receiving.

Comment: can you share your whole html code??

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reproduce this error. Here is my code

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   <div class="field">
      <label>Profile Picture</label>
      <input class="button" type="file" name="profilepic">
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="submit">
   </div>
</form>

$target_dir = "../img/";
$newprofilepic = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($newprofilepic, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

And this error doesn't appear for me. Are you using `enctype="multipar/form-data"` in your form tag?

This error can appear if this key doesn't exist in your `$_FILES` array. Please check it using `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: I've now got the string name uploading to a mysql table however I am having issues with uploading the actual image to the server so that it can be displayed correctly from the table onto the website?

Comment: How are you put file to the server? Using copy() method? Just make copy($_FILES['profilepic']['tmp_name'], 'your_file_name.jpg') check if everything were good, only then add new row to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined index:  is a common error when you are calling an element of an array or object but that element does not exist. For example if in the below $_FILES array there is no "profilepic" element you would get this error.

$_FILES ["profilepic"]["name"]